# Sound Issue: Dummy Output in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: sound, 20.04

I am facing an issue with sound output and input.
It can read from an external BlueTooth headset but won't show internal output hardware(I have a monitor with a built-in speaker on it) or front panel input (I am using Desktop).

Image

[image: img_sound_issue]